# how to eliminate duplicate results from joined sql statement

Tags: sql, inner-join

i have four tables which are related like this:

```
TABLE A: 1 to many with TABLE B
TABLE B: 1 to many with TABLE C
TABLE D: many to 1 with TABLE B
```

I would like to create a result set which contains no duplicates.

```
SELECT A.f1
       A.f2
       B.f1
       C.f1
       D.f1
from   A LEFT JOIN (B INNER JOIN D on D.fk_b = B.id) on A.id = B.fk_a
         LEFT JOIN C on C.fk_b = B.id
```

Some but not all records are duplicated. Only the records from `TABLE D` which have the same FK to `TABLE B`.

If there are 2 the same `D.fk_B` fields then i would like to select only the first one. My `INNER JOIN` would become something like:

```
B INNER JOIN TOP 1 D on.....
```

But that's not possible?

Thank you!

Comment: If they are exact duplicates you should use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: no there not exact duplicates :(

Comment: Define what you mean by "inexact duplicate".

Comment: The rows are duplicates, only 1 field in table D is different for the two.

Comment: perhaps you can provide some sample data/expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the structure in question is near the one shown bellow,

> > [image: Tables]

The following SELECT statement will show you just the primary keys, briefly giving an idea about what data is being returned.

```
SELECT
  A.id AS `A_id`,
  B.id AS `B_id`,
  COALESCE(C.id, 0) AS `C_id`,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT D.id FROM D WHERE D.fk_b = B.id LIMIT 1), 0
  ) AS `D_id`
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON (B.fk_a = A.id)
LEFT JOIN C ON (B.id = C.fk_b);
```

Now the select you've asked for:

```
SELECT
  A.f1 AS `A_f1`,
  A.f2 AS `A_f2`,
  B.f1 AS `B_f1`,
  COALESCE(C.f1, '-') AS `C_f1`,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT D.f1 FROM D WHERE D.fk_b = B.id LIMIT 1), '-'
  ) AS `D_f1`
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON (B.fk_a = A.id)
LEFT JOIN C ON (B.id = C.fk_b);
```

*Code above was tested and worked fine on MySQL 5.6*

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.f1
       A.f2
       B.f1
       C.f1
       D.f1
from   A LEFT JOIN (B INNER JOIN D on D.fk_b = B.id) on A.id = B.fk_a
         LEFT JOIN C on C.fk_b = B.id
```

You can do this:

```
B INNER JOIN TOP 1 D on.....
```

Like this

```
B INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 fields from table) D ON ...
```

Try this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT A.f1
           A.f2
           B.f1
           C.f1
           D.f1
    from   A 
    LEFT JOIN (B INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT fk_b FROM D) D on D.fk_b = B.id) 
         on A.id = B.fk_a
    LEFT JOIN C on C.fk_b = B.id
```

Comment: B INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 fields from table) D ON ... gives me a syntax error (do i literally use "table" or my table name? Which would be D right?

Comment: Use your table name and field list

Comment: You can replace a table name (in this case D) with a SQL query (select top 1 from D).   However, your example isn't too clear, but I'll modify the answer query to do what I think you want...

Comment: hi sparky, i get a syntax error here ... D on D.fk_b = B.id) the field name D.fk_b isnt recognized. 
Thanks for your help i magened to solve this problem by removing table D and using another date field.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you have cartesian join.

You could try just putting DISTINCT infront of you column definition or you could so subqueries to link the tables together.

Comment: I guess i have to use subqueries. Was mostly wondering whether it could be done more elegantly.